# How to change the system's audio volume using Win32 function called via PInvoke from Managed Code

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to change the audio volume of the system by making a Win32 API call in my C# WPF application. Every site I've looked at showed code similar to the following:

```
double val_c = 0;

private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    const uint WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;
    const uint APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 10;
    const uint APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 9;
    const uint APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 8;

    IntPtr handy = this.Handle;

    if (slider1.Value < val_c)
    {
        Win32.Win32.SendMessage(handy, WM_APPCOMMAND, handy, new IntPtr(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN));
    }
    else
    {
        Win32.Win32.SendMessage(handy, WM_APPCOMMAND, handy, new IntPtr(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP));
    }
    val_c = slider1.Value;
}
```

I can't figure out where to specify the exact value I'm trying to set.

By what value does the above code increment the volume by? Actually, despite the above being posted on several forums, blogs, etc, I can't get it to work. It only works if you add a "* 0x10000" to the last argument. Even then I can't figure out the significance of it.

I have the above set to execute when a slider's (with a min of 0 and a max of 100) value changes, but the slider isn't in sync with the actual system volume. Just setting the slider to 25 could set the system volume to 100.

Comment: Clearly your problem is that the commands are *incremental* and your slider is absolute.  Changing the absolute value of the volume can't be done the easy way, you'll need to use mmsystem or waspi functions.  Wrapped by the naudio library, for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two problems. One is the definition of the message parameters, which should be as follows

```
const uint WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;
const uint APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;
const uint APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
const uint APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
```

The other is that you need to apply the up/down change a number of times depending on the difference between the current value of your slider and the previous value.

So, something like this (note that the message arguments should only be cast as `IntPtr` and not `new`'ed

```
if (slider1.Value < val_c)
{
    int nDiff = (int)(val_c - slider1.Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < nDiff; ++i)
    {
        Win32.Win32.SendMessage(handy, WM_APPCOMMAND, handy, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);
    }
}
else
{
    int nDiff = (int)(slider1.Value - val_c);
    for (int i = 0; i < nDiff; ++i)
    {
        Win32.Win32.SendMessage(handy, WM_APPCOMMAND, handy, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
    }
}
```

The above code could be simplified somewhat:

```
IntPtr pArg = (slider1.Value < val_c) ? (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN : (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP;
int nDiff = (int)Math.Abs(val_c - slider1.Value);
for (int i = 0; i < nDiff; ++i)
{
    Win32.Win32.SendMessage(handy, WM_APPCOMMAND, handy, pArg);
}
```

The only other thing is that you will need to know the current volume setting when your application starts, so that you can set the slider to the correct initial value.

There is a (more complex) [tutorial here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45693-controlling-sound-volume-in-c#/) that shows how you can possibly do that, although it may be more practical for you to initially set the volume to some known value when you begin (i.e. set volume down 100 times to ensure it's zero on start up).

Comment: Thanks! Your code works! I think I was confused on the declarations because according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275(v=vs.85).aspx, the commands aren't hex values. MS gives them a decimals, which, unless I read them wrong, really screwed me up. So thanks.

Comment: @Nickersoft - I see, that's because MSDN shows the values that go in the high-order word of the parameter, glad you're sorted. If this is the correct answer for you, don't forget to click the check mark to make it green to show this answer as accepted.