# Using NAudio, is there a way to access the different levels of a device?

Tags: c#, naudio

Using NAudio, I have found my Speakers playback device with the following code:

```
MMDevice? Speakers = null;
var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
foreach (var endpoint in enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active))
{
    Console.WriteLine(endpoint.FriendlyName);
    if (endpoint.FriendlyName == "Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)" ||
        endpoint.FriendlyName == "Speakers (Realtek(R) Audio)")
    {
        Speakers = endpoint;
        break;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do with it is change the levels that are present in the Windows UI:

[image: SpeakersLevels]

So far I have only been able to change the master volume, the one represented by the top slider. Is it possible to change the others, and how?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005841/how-to-change-the-systems-audio-volume-using-win32-function-called-via-pinvoke and http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WM.html